# how to pass the request data from spring boot controller to the apache camel route

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

**UseCase:** In my app have one REST Controller, developed with the help of the Spring boot, my requirement is, I have to pass the request data from controller to the route, from route again need to pass data to MQ

Here how can I pass the **inputReq** data from controller to the route? could anyone please help

```
@Controller
public class RequestController {

    @PostMapping("/request")
    public String requestMapping(@RequestBody String inputReq) {
        new ProduceRouter();  // instance of the apache camel route
        return null;

    }
}
```

Below one the apache camel route:

```
@Component
public class ProduceRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
            
        .from("jms:RequestQueue?disableReplyTo=true")
        .log("Received Body is  ${body}   and header info is   ${headers}  ");

        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Controller, autowire an instance of the CamelContext and ProducerTemplate.

```
@Autowired
private CamelContext camelContext;
@Autowired
private ProducerTemplate producer;
```

You then need to create an exchange request with the ExchangeBuilder and add your request body .

```
Exchange exchangeRequest = ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(camelContext)
.withBody(inputReq).build();
```

You can then call the send method on the producer object to tap into your route and capture the response.

```
Exchange exchangeResponse = producer.send("direct:startRoute", exchangeRequest).
```

Then in your route file, you can consume from `direct:startRoute`

Comment: is producer object predefined one? and could you please suggest any resources/books work with spring boot and apache camel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , could you please suggest any books/resources for apache camel with spring boot, I'm facing lot of problems while developing

Comment: no the producer needs to be Autowired as well. I will fix my answer. There are no resources specific to spring boot. The camel website is quite comprehensive in that respect!